# MySQL Workbench How can I run the same query using each line of the file as input?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

So, this is going to go back a bit... The last time I had to do something like this I was using Watcom Sybase SQLAnywhere 5.0 for OS/2. To preemptively answer the question: Yes, I have indoor plumbing! :)

On that platform I was able to write "parameter-ized" queries and then execute those queries over a comma-separated file of records. e.g.:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = "%parameter_one%" WHERE other_column_name = "%parameter_two%";
```

There were some other set up lines above it to equate the parameter names with the fields from the file, but you get the gist. This query above would be saved as an .sql file and then executed in the interactive SQL browser as

```
READ my_parameterized_query.sql my_file_full_of_data.csv
```

Is it possible to do this or something similar with MySQL Workbench? ...or do I need to learn Python?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible with MySQL Workbench, but is a nice idea. I'll take this into our FR list, if you don't mind.

I'm afraid you have to write a little application to do what you want here. It doesn't matter which language you choose, unless you want to create a plugin in WB (which requires Python).

As a start: use a prepared statement and bind the values to the parameters for each line in the file.